# Where do I download these files from and what do I need exactly for AJAX 4.0

Tags: asp.net, ajax, .net-4.0

MicrosoftAjaxDataContext.js
MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0909/MicrosoftAjaxDataContext.js
- http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0909/MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.js

Just a simple Bing search for both external javascript files. Note however that these are Beta versions as I don't think that these got into final release.